# How do I only allow authenticated users to interact with Organic Groups "groups"?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users, domain-access

Organic Groups 7.x-2.6
Domain Access 7.x-3.11
Domain Access Bridge (module that ties DA and OG together)

Hello, I am using Organic Groups with Domain Access.
I found I was unable to only allow authenticated users to see/post/subscribe to groups.

Someone mentioned Access Control.  I am using Domain Access and tried installing Access Control on top of Domain Access and Organic Groups.  I was able to only allow authenticated individuals to interact with groups, but I ran into an issue where if a group was set to "private" only group admins could see the group, even if the non group admin was actually a member of the group.  With Domain Access and OG it is not recommended to install another access control module, so it is not surprising this combination failed.

This really seems like this should be a part of OG (a sentiment that I have heard quite a bit on the net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question.
There is no access control with organic groups which disallows anonymous users from seeing public organic groups.
You can use the "Domain Strict" module and have the website that the organic groups is to be hosted on not allow "Anonymous" users to view that domain.  This is a configuration option with Domain Strict.

This has the desired effect.  The only downside is that your domain which hosts your organic groups will not allow anyone who is not authenticated to view any content on said domain.

To change this go to Structure-->domains-->User Defaults
find your domain that will hold your OG groups and uncheck "Anonymous User"
Click save configuration.

Tada!